# Sorting a table in html using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how I can sort different columns in HTML. Right now, I have a button that sorts the first column (last name) in descending order. But now I'd like to create a second button, that sorts the 3rd column (Gender) by type.

Here is a link to what I currently have:
https://codepen.io/Pcollins10/pen/Wyxpyy

```js
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      //check if the two rows should switch place:
      if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="sortTable()">Output 3 (Last Name..descending):</button></p>
<table id="myTable">
   <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Birth Date</th>
    <th>Favorite Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Kournikova</td>
    <td>Anna</td>
    <td>Female</td>
    <td>6/3/1975</td>
    <td>Red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hingis</td>
    <td>Martina</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>4/2/1979</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Seles</td>
    <td>Monica</td>
    <td>Female</td>
    <td>12/2/1973</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ambercrombie</td>
    <td>Neil</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>2/13/1943</td>
    <td>Tan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bishop</td>
    <td>Timothy</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>4/23/1967</td>
    <td>Yellow</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kelly</td>
    <td>Sue</td>
    <td>Female</td>
    <td>7/12/1959</td>
    <td>Pink</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Steve</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>3/3/1985</td>
    <td>Red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bonk</td>
    <td>Radek</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>6/3/1975</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bouillon</td>
    <td>Francis</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>6/3/1975</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
</table>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSTrG.png)

If possible, I'd like to be able to first sort by gender type, then (if the gender is the same), sort by last name.

See below for example.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing this to exercise your programming skills? If not, I recommend to use some widget library that supports sorted tables.

Comment: Instead of sorting html nodes, I prefer to just use Array.sort() on the data and just rerender the entire table.

Comment: how I can I arrange the data into a table like form using array?